# flatlist showing type error : null is not a key

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I am getting this error while trying to fetch data from React Native. Earlier it was working fine but now it is not working and I can't find out why.

[image]

```js
<FlatList
  data={this.state.favArr}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.itemContainer}
      onPress={() => this.handleTap({ item })}
    >
      <Image
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={styles.contentImage}
        source={{
          uri: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/186077/pexels-photo-186077.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"
        }}
      />

      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => this.unFavButtonTapped({ item })}
        style={styles.unFavBtnStyle}
      >
        <Image
          style={{
            height: 25,
            width: 25,
            alignSelf: "center"
          }}
          source={require("../Assets/ic_fill_heart.png")}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <View style={styles.apartment}>
        <Text style={fontLoaded ? styles.itemLocationFont : styles.item}>
          {item.bedroom} BHK Apartment{" "}
        </Text>

        <Text
          style={fontLoaded ? styles.LocationitemAveniur : styles.Locationitem}
        >
          {item.area}, {item.city}
        </Text>

        <Text style={fontLoaded ? styles.feetitemAveniur : styles.feetitem}>
          {item.builtUpArea} ft.{" "}
        </Text>

        <Text style={fontLoaded ? styles.itemLocationFont : styles.item}>
          ₹{item.price}{" "}
        </Text>

        <Text style={fontLoaded ? styles.RightItemAveniur : styles.Rightitem}>
          Posted On {item.uploadDate}
        </Text>
        <Text style={fontLoaded ? styles.expiryItemAveniur : styles.expiryItem}>
          Expires On {item.expiryDate}
        </Text>

        {
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.handleUnfavourite({ item })}>
            <Text style={styles.UnFavitem}>UnFavourite</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        }
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
  keyExtractor={item => item.key}
  numColumns={numColumns}
/>
```

Comment: What's wrong with my answer Rishav?!

Answer (score 2):

replace this line:

```
keyExtractor={item => item.key}
```

with:

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but the error was in authentication in my firebase. I fixed that. I really appreciate your answer : )

Comment: well, your solution was also used and this worked too : )